# ExtJS DirectStore set param value

Tags: extjs

In the EXTJS DirectStore, I want to set parameter vaule and then reload it. how to do it ?

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.DirectStore({
            directFn: Report.ReadReport,
            autoLoad: false,
            paramsAsHash: false,
            paramOrder: 'identifier',
            root: 'Report',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            fields: [
                { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
                ],
            remoteSort: true,
            listeners: {
                load: function (store, recs, opt) {
                    myGrid.setHeight(400);
                    myGrid.doLayout();
                }
            }
        });
```

what I want is like this

```
myStore.param.'identifier'.value = '12345'
myStore.load();
```

how to do it ? is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
myStore.load({
    params: {
        identifier: 12345
    }
});
```